Highlight shortest path between two clickable graph vertices
Having a Graph I wish to implement the following:
1) When clicking on one vertex it changes the vertex color and displays its name.
2) After clicking on a second vertex 1) happens and also the shortest possible path between both vertices is highlighted.
I got to implement 1) as below but I can't see a direct way to generate the shortest path between the two chosen vertices.
  graphTrial = {1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 6, 4 <-> 6, 1 <-> 5, 5 <-> 4, 6 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4}; 
  DynamicModule[{graph}, Dynamic[graph], 
                 Initialization :> (graph = Graph[graphTrial, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VertexShapeFunction -> 
   (EventHandler[Disk[#1, 0.2], "MouseClicked" :> (graph = HighlightGraph[graph, #2,VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20]]; ), Method -> "Queued"] & )]; 
     graph = SetProperty[graph, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[graph]])]


FindShortestPath

I've tried to minimally changed your code to make it work. I've made an auxiliary function which takes a graph and a list of selected nodes, highlight them, and the shortest path between them as calculated via FindShortestPath.
plotGraph[g_, selected_] := 
  HighlightGraph[g, {Style[selected, Red], 
    If[Length[selected] == 2, 
      Style[PathGraph[
        FindShortestPath[g, selected[[1]], selected[[2]]]], Red, Thick]]}];

SeedRandom[123];
graphTrial = RandomGraph[{10, 20}];

DynamicModule[{graph, selected = {}},
 Dynamic[plotGraph[graph, selected]],
 Initialization :> (graph = 
    Graph[graphTrial, 
     VertexShapeFunction -> (EventHandler[Disk[#1, 0.1], 
         "MouseClicked" :> (selected = Take[Prepend[selected, #2], UpTo[2]])] &)])
 ]


You can change the behaviour of selecting nodes by changing the code for selected = ....

Wow, surprising, super thanks.
